# Slow UITableView with UIScrollView and PageControl inside each custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm working on iOS app in Swift 2.0 and having troubles to make UITableView load fast, it takes ~1-2sec for now to load.

**What I have.**

I have a UITableView with custom cells. Each custom cell has UIScrollView and PageControl for horizontal scrolling.

There's also a separate xib to be added on each page of UIScrollView. This xib contains view with two UIViewPickers.

**How it works**

In "tablewView: cellForRowAtIndexPath" I'm calling a function that instantiates subviews using xib file and filling it with data. It then adds it to scrollView and configures paging.

**What's slow**

If I add 10-20 pages to 3 cells it's already slow as hell (1-3sec).

I've tried moving the logic with filling the data into subViews in a background thread and adding those subViews to cells later in main thread. It made the whole tableView appear quickly but it's still stupid how long you need to wait to see the actual data inside each cell.

I looked into Instruments and it seems to me that all my data calculation is pretty fast, but adding those subViews with uipickers is the slowest part.

I've also tried to add only first subView and then add all the rest if user starts to scroll horizontally on cells. It's like 10 times faster but the lag is still notable and the logic is way more complicated (adding new subview on scroll drag is not very straightforward).

Any better suggestions on where should I look and how to make the whole concept working fast? I'm sure it can be fast just need to improve the logic.

Comment: Can you post some code? like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , ...

Comment: Sure. Here're all related functions: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81986debb1f6d5fd1c79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "add only first subView and then add all the rest if user starts to scroll horizontally on cells." is good. I suggest this: Load first subView. Then load other with sleep time. Something like:

```
// load others, 
notMainthread{
  for (...subviews){
    mainThread{
      loadSubView();
    }
    sleep(0.01);
  }
}
```

I don't know swift, so I wrote a pseudo code. 
Link app what I did for loading too many subviews: https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/liveradio/id998787831

Some code:

```
    // running on not main thread    
    for (int i=0; i<[listCT count]; i++) {
        ...
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            emptyImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, yEndLast, cWidthTop, yStart-yEndLast);
            [emptyImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
            [contentView addSubview:emptyImage];
        });
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.004];
    }
```